# No seleccionar caracteres intermedios en una regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Estaba haciendo una `regex` que extrae los `tags` de `html` de un `string` para solo dejar el texto entre estas.. Ej:

```
"<a href='#'>go to <b>start</b> page</a>" 
capturo: <a href='#'>, <b>, </b> y </a>
resultado = go to start page
```

```
"<div>prueba</div>"
capturo: <div> y </div>
resultado = prueba
```

**Mi regex es la siguiente:**

```
var reg = new Regex((\<.+\>)|(\<\/.+\>)|(\<.+\/>), 'g')
```

Esta pensada para que si encuentra un `tag` de tipo `<tag>`, `</tag>` o `<tag/>` haga match para luego hacer un `replace` con mí regex y así solo me quedaría el texto... Pero me hace match también de los caracteres intermedios... He probado varias cosas utilizando `(?:)` para que no capture los caracteres entre los dos `tag` pero no me funciona.

**También probé con**:

```
\<.+\>(?:.)+\<\/.+\>
```

***Me gustaría de ser posible saber como no hacer match a caracteres en el medio de una `regex`...***

[Pruebas de la regex](https://regexr.com/4q9dt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo tuve que hacer algo parecido, si recuerdo bien use algo parecido a esto.

```js
var content = [
   "<a required='ok' asdas='asdasd'>1<b>2</b></a>", // 12
   "<a required>1<b>2</b></a>", // 12
   '<a required href="asdasdasdasd"       >1<b>2</b></a>', // 12
   "<a>1<b>2</b></a> 3 </c>", // 12 3
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 </c>", // 12 3
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 <d-2-0> hello </d-2-0>  </c>", // 12 3 hello  
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 <d-2-0> hello </d-2-0> c </c>", // 12 3 hello < 
]; 

var reg = /<.+?>/g


content.forEach(s => console.log(s + ' => ', s.replace(reg, '')))
```

**EDIT:**

Si lo que buscas es obtener el contenido de un elemento HTML como texto, es decir eliminando etiquetas, se puede hacer gracias a la propiedad `innerText` o `textContent`. Podrías incluso crear un elemento en memoria, añadir el contenido como innerHTML y luego usar los metodos mencionados anteriormente.

```js
console.log('innerText', container.innerText)
console.log('textContent', container.textContent)
```

```html
<div id="container" class="mi-clase">
  Mi contenido
  <br>
  <p foo="bar"> más contenido </p>
  <p data-otro-atributo="foo" >aquí (  ) van dos espacios</p>
</div>
```

`innerText` Uno de los incovenientes de este método es que devuelve un solo espacio en el caso de encontrar varios seguidos.

Aconsejo usar en su lugar `textContent`.

**NOTA**

En el código de ejemplo anterior aplicamos sobre un elemento existente.
En el ejemplo siguiente generamos todo en memoria a partir de una cadena de texto.

```js
function extraerTexto(contenido) {
 var contenedor = document.createElement('div');
 contenedor.innerHTML = contenido;
 var texto = contenedor.textContent;
 contenedor = null;
 return texto;
}

var content = [
   "<a>1<b>2</b></a>", // 12
   "<a>1<b>2</b></a> 3 </c>", // 12 3
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 </c>", // 12 3
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 <d-2-0> hello </d-2-0>  </c>", // 12 3 hello  
   "<a-1>1<b>2</b></a1> 3 <d-2-0> hello </d-2-0> < </c>", // 12 3 hello < 
   `  Mi contenido
  <br>
  <p foo="bar"> más contenido </p>
  <p data-otro-atributo="foo" >aquí (  ) van dos espacios</p>`
];

 
content.forEach(s => console.log(extraerTexto(s)))
```

Comment: gracias por responder Angel..  el problema es que esta regex para tags de tipo: `"<a href='\#'>"` o `"<img src='\home.jpg'/>"` esta dejando de hacer match pero veo funciona mejor que la mia

Comment: @RazerJs ahora vero el problema con los atributos. Una idea es usar la api del navegador. 
1 - Crear un nuevo elemento en memoria `document.createElement('div')` 
2 - Añades el contentido con `innerHTML`. 
3 - Lees el innerText de este elemento.

Comment: Saludos Angel el problema es que recibo como parámetro esta cadena.. no precisamente un tag con sus atributos e hijos.. por eso el utilizar una regex

Comment: @RazerJs  creo que no pillastes la idea (agrego otro ejemplo), seria totalmente valido pasar este contenido a un nuevo elemento en memoria y obtener textContent

Comment: Si yo habia entendido solo que me parecía mas trabajoso hacer una función para generar el html y luego.. nunca he utilizado el textContent, pensaba que tendria que hacer textContent a cada tag que generara.. lo veo

Comment: @RazerJs de todas formas acabo de añadir un ejemplo que solo usa una expresion regular :)

Comment: jaja genial... gracias amigo que me parece muy buena tu respuesta son como tres en una... pero esta ultima regex no funciona bien para el caso de los `<img src="link" />` o `<hr />` ni `<html lang = 'es' >`  me parece que cambiandola por `/(\<(\w|.)+?\>)|(\<\/(\w|.)+?\>)/g` parecida a tu primera ya funcionaria ;-)

Comment: al parecer la clave esta en el `+?`

Comment: @RazerJs si , ya veo, tampoco funcionaría en el caso de que los atributos contengan como valor caracteres escapados que confundan a la regEx, tales como  `<a b="\" \\ >" >link</a>`. Como dije antes, siempre que sea posible usar la API  del navegador nos ahorraremos tener que cubrir estos casos. 
Pero me alegro que te sirva para ayudarte a buscar una regExp que cubra tu necesidades :)